# How to download and silent install .exe file with given URL using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a URL which is a download link to a software .exe file.
The intended operation is to use Python 3 to download the said file and then do a silent installation.

```
import ssl
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests

#convert to string
url = str(url) 

#convert ftp download path to http and remove chars to make it downloadable 
httpurl = re.sub("ftp://","https://",url)
print("url is: " + url)


#function to break file name from the full path
def split(downloadurl):
    p,downloadexename = os.path.split(downloadurl)
    return [downloadexename]

#Remove all the unnecessary stuff you don't need
downloadurl = httpurl.replace("'","").replace(',','').replace(":2100/FTP Folders/Software","").replace(" ","%20").strip("(").strip(")")
print("Download URL is: "+downloadurl)

down_name = os.path.basename(downloadurl)
down_dir = r"C:\Desktop"
                 
#Create folder if it doesn't exist for download as required 
if not os.path.exists(down_dir):
    os.makedirs(down_dir)
full_path = os.path.join(down_dir, down_name)

# Silent Install
subprocess.call([full_path, '/Silent'], shell=True)
```

Comment: windows won't let You do it silently it will first ask if You allow this program to make changes on Your computer, download maybe You can but probably not install (at least not silently I don't think)

Comment: @Matiiss I have made the respective changes to Windows UAC. How do I execute that not silently

Comment: My only idea is using pyautogui but other than that I haven't had experience with this so I have no idea.

Comment: @Matiissis it possible to do it via python call to cmd?

Comment: it will still probably ask for user input: to press the button

Comment: @Matiiss Please check the edited code. I managed to get the debug errors resolved but I do not see the file being downloaded. Could you give it a try please?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of installer the `.exe` is, but there is a high chance it already has the ability to install silently. For example, InnoSetup installers (a very common type) use the parameter `/SILENT`. If you don't know the installer type, you may try running the `.exe` with different variants of `/s`, `/S`, `/SILENT` etc. -- or some variants of `/?`, `--help` to show command line usage.

Comment: The exe is built with silent install but the download doesn't start nor did the code show any debugging errors.

Comment: so wait, the donwload didn't start of the install? (I think there is a difference)

Comment: @matiiss download, install none happened.

Comment: @Matiiss So what exactly is your question then? You showed a code that downloads an exe, is that code not working? Question title suggested that you were struggling with the second part -- running it silently.

Comment: @JanPokorný why are You asking me I am not the OP? also OP mentioned struggle installing not running it silently. Also as far as I know whenever one tries to install an exe windows prompts whether the user allows it

Comment: That's correct. I am unable to even download thus cannot install either. But to answer your question, no the code above does not work for any of it

Comment: @Matiiss Sorry, meant to tag the OP. If you mean the UAC prompt, that depends entirely on the program being installed, some are able to install to in user-only mode that does not require admin rights.

@user15639713 Are you able to download the file using `curl`?

Comment: @JanPokorný I haven't tried curl, in this case pycurl might be helpful. Can it download exe files though?

Comment: @user15639713 I'm just asking to check that it's actually possible to download the file programatically, perhaps there's some proxy misconfiguration or required auth etc... All libraries that download files are able to download .exe, it's all just data

Comment: @Matiiss I figured it out, updated the finished code.

Comment: @user15639713 I suggest You would add an answer Yourself with what You found and explain (at least try) how/why it works, and leave the error code in the question that way people that come by with the same issue have the problem and solution stated